# API endpoint to execute send emails using the credentials previous stored in the database. (Using Gmail REST API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, gmail-api

I've got an assignment, and they have asked me to obtain user credentials using OAuth 2.0 and save it in a database (say MongoDB). I was able to complete this step.

The second task is to have an API endpoint to execute send emails using the credentials previous stored. (Using Gmail REST API). I am struggling with this second task and have been searching all over the internet.

PS: I'm doing it in Nodejs

Answer (score 1):

- Documentation : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs
- Setup Gmail REST API and get your clientId and client secret
- write a function to send email
- i have used nodemailar in example, should be similar to gmail

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var crypto = require('crypto');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: 'apikey',
        pass: 'Your Key'
    }
});

function generateVerificationToken() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
}

exports.addUserEmail = function (req, res) {
    Users.find({ email: req.body.email }, (err, users) => {
        if (err) { res.send("Err"); return }
        if (users.length == 0) {
            var user = new Users(req.body);

            user.verification.verification_token = generateVerificationToken();

            user.save(function (err, email) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                sendVerificationEmail(req, user.verification.verification_token, email.email, (err) => {
                    if (err) { console.log(err); return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                    res.status(200).send({ 
                        'A verification email has been sent to ' : email.email 
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            res.status(400).send({ Error : 'Invalid Request',
                Error : 'This email is already Registered'
            });
        }
    });
};

function sendVerificationEmail(req, token, email, cb) {
    let emailText = 'Hello,\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp:\/\/' + req.headers.host + '\/user\/verify\/?token=' + token + '&email=' + email + '.\n';
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'donotreply@Express-Server.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Account Verification Token',
        text: emailText
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
        cb(err);
    });

}
```

In your route

```
    app.route('/user/register')
    .post(users.addUserEmail);
```